# store the result of output in a matrix in R

Tags: loops

I want to save the output of a loop in a matrix. while I created the matrix with the desirable size but I do not know what should I do in the next step. this is my code:

```
d=6
K=4
ord=matrix(rep(0,d*2),d,2)
for (ii in 1:K){
    for (jj in 1:K){
              if (ii != jj &f[ii,jj]>threshold){
                  print(c(jj,ii))}}}
```

the output is :

```
[1] 2 1
[1] 4 1
[1] 4 2
[1] 1 3
[1] 2 3
[1] 4 3
```

I want to store the result of output in the matrix ord.

Answer (score 0):

You can find an example here

https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-intro.html#Index-matrices

Or you start from the beginning of arrays and matrices:

https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-intro.html#Arrays-and-matrices

Add a row index variable and increment it, whenever you stored a value pair into this row of the matrix.

EDIT:
as the question looks like some kind of students home work I wanted to be not so explicit with the solution. But moderators say otherwise, here you go with a MWE (minimal working example):

```
d=6
K=4
ord=matrix(rep(0,d*2),d,2)
row=1
f=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
f=matrix(f,4,4)
threshold=4
for (ii in 1:K){
    for (jj in 1:K){
        if (ii != jj &f[ii,jj]>threshold){
            print(c(jj,ii))
            ord[row,]=c(jj,ii)
            row=row+1
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).